# Why isn't my parameterized query working?

Tags: c#, t-sql, .net-3.5

I have a kinda complex query, basically I search the database in most fields for a string or strings. If it's multiple strings, the database field must match all parts of the strings.

This is the base sql that the query is built on:

```
SELECT wo.ID, {columns} FROM tblWorkOrder wo
    LEFT JOIN tblWorkOrderCategory wc
    ON wo.CategoryID = wo.ID
    LEFT JOIN tblTenant t
    ON wo.TenantID = t.ID
    LEFT JOIN tblProperty p
    ON wo.PropertyID = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN tblRentalUnit ru
    ON wo.UnitID = ru.ID
```

Columns is replaced with this list:

```
            "wo.Date", "wo.WorkDesc", "wo.Priority", "wo.WorkDoneBy", "wo.EstimatedCost", "wo.DueDate", "wo.ActualCost", "wo.FinishedDate", "wo.workOrderNum",
            "wc.[Description]",
            "t.TenantName",
            "p.PropertyName",
            "ru.UnitNumber"
```

and this is how I build the query:

```
        String[] parts = txtSearch.Text.Split(' ');
        foreach (String column in columnsToSearch) {
            String clause = " (";
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++) {
                clause += column + " LIKE '%@param" + i + "%' ";
                if (i + 1 != parts.Length) {
                    clause += "AND ";
                }
            }
            clause = clause.TrimEnd() + ") ";
            sql += clause + " OR ";
        }
        sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { 'O', 'R', ' ' });

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(RentalEase.Properties.Settings.Default.RentalEaseConnectionString)) {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++) {
                command.Parameters.Add("@param" + i, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = parts[i];
                //command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("@param" + i, parts[i]);
            }
```

Only this always returns no rows. However, in the for loop that assigns the parameter values, if I comment out the Parameters.Add line and uncomment the one below it, I wind up with results like I should be seeing. As this is an unsafe way to do it, I'd like to know why using parameters is failing.

Comment: Have you tried just printing out the resulting query to see what your code is actually submitting to the db?

Comment: I can print out the query with the @param[0-x], but SqlCommand doesn't as far as I know, allow me to print out the resulting query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the *literal* `'@Param'`; you mean:

```
... LIKE '%' + @param" + i + " + '%' ...
```

so that the TSQL is:

```
... LIKE '%' + @param2 + '%' ...
```

Or simpler; put the `'%'` into the value in the calling code; then your code becomes:

```
... LIKE @param" + i + " ...
```

and the TSQL becomes:

```
... LIKE @param2 ...
```

Comment: The @param2 is replaced with a specific value, so it should look like `x LIKE '%blah%'`

Comment: @Malfist - no, that isn't how parameterisation works. In the middle of a string i.e. `'%@param2%'` it is **not** a parameter, but just some character data that happens to be an `@`, a `p`, a `a`, a `r`, a `a`, a `m` and a `2`. It *is* a parameter here though: `'%' + @param2 + '%'`

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Profiler - you'll see exactly what gets sent to SQL Server, including all your parameters and their values.

Copy and paste that into SQL Server Mgmt Studio and run it - I'm sure you'll find out what's causing the issue... or if not, you can always post the parametrized query here and we'll help again :-)

Comment: I don't have the SQL Profiler, I only have the express version of SQL Server 2008

Comment: @malfist: ok, next time you ought to mention such an important fact in your original question!